Correct usage: "Which" or "that" in a trailing em dash clause
In the case of a trailing em dash clause, should one use "which" or "that" to add qualifying detail about an object that has been previously introduced?
To make use of a concrete example, which of the following examples is correct?


The organization responded to allegations that the manager committed a bad action by relaying the manager's defence against those allegations—a defence which contains many falsehoods.




The organization responded to allegations that the manager committed a bad action by relaying the manager's defence against those allegations—a defence that contains many falsehoods.



Have you looked up previous questions about that or which? I'm sure this has already been sufficiently covered here.

Welcome to ELU. It’s expected here that one do some research before posting a question, and share that result in the post. In this case—as with so many other questions—the answer depends on context and on the meaning one intends to convey. The presence of the dash doesn’t affect the choice between that and which.

Both are fine, so a matter of personal choice. The relative clause modifies the second "defence".

In a comment BillJ wrote:

Both are fine, so a matter of personal choice. The relative clause modifies the second "defence".

